# React Native - requireNativeComponent: 'RTCVideoView' was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, webrtc

This is my Code:

```
            import React, { Component } from 'react';
            // import { Platform } from 'react-native';
            import {
                RTCPeerConnection,
                RTCMediaStream,
                RTCIceCandidate,
                RTCSessionDescription,
                RTCView,
                MediaStreamTrack,
                getUserMedia,
            } from 'react-native-webrtc';

            class App extends Component {
                // Initial state
                state = {
                    videoURL: null,
                    isFront: true
                }

                componentDidMount() {
                    const configuration = { "iceServers": [{ "url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }] };
                    const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
                    const { isFront } = this.state;
                    MediaStreamTrack.getSources(sourceInfos => {
                        console.log('MediaStreamTrack.getSources', sourceInfos);
                        let videoSourceId;
                        for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
                            const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
                            // I like ' than "
                            if (sourceInfo.kind === 'video' && sourceInfo.facing === (isFront ? 'front' : 'back')) {
                                videoSourceId = sourceInfo.id;
                            }
                        }
                        getUserMedia({
                            audio: true,
                            // THIS IS FOR SIMULATOR ONLY
                            // In fact, you better test on real iOS/Android device
                            // We just can test audio on simulator, so i set video = false
                            // video: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? false : {
                            video: {
                                mandatory: {
                                    minWidth: 500, // Provide your own width, height and frame rate here
                                    minHeight: 300,
                                    minFrameRate: 30
                                },
                                facingMode: (isFront ? 'user' : 'environment'),
                                optional: (videoSourceId ? [{ sourceId: videoSourceId }] : [])
                            }
                        }, (stream) => {
                            // use arrow function :)
                            // (stream) or stream are fine
                            console.log('Streaming OK', stream);
                            this.setState({
                                videoURL: stream.toURL()
                            });
                            pc.addStream(stream);
                        }, error => {
                            console.log('Oops, we getting error', error.message);
                            throw error;
                        });
                    });
                    pc.createOffer((desc) => {
                        pc.setLocalDescription(desc, () => {
                            // Send pc.localDescription to peer
                            console.log('pc.setLocalDescription');
                        }, (e) => { throw e; });
                    }, (e) => { throw e; });

                    pc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
                        // send event.candidate to peer
                        console.log('onicecandidate', event);
                    };

                }

                render() {
                    return (
                        <RTCView streamURL={this.state.videoURL} style={styles.container} />
                    );
                }
            }
            const styles = {
                container: {
                    flex: 1,
                    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: '#000'
                }
            };

            export default App;
```

Why do i keep getting the error on line int he title of the question?.

```
<RTCView streamURL={this.state.videoURL} style={styles.container} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is common problem when you forgot to do `npx pod-install`